# ORACLE sql: Return columns associated with MAX value of a subquery that SUM values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having issues with a problem where I'm only supposed to use subqueries.  I have the find the names of Authors of the book(s) that have been sold the most.  What I have works if there is only one row that matches the MAX value of totalsold.

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM Books b
JOIN BookAuthor ba ON b.isbn = ba.isbn
JOIN Author a ON ba.authorid = a.authorid
WHERE b.isbn =
    (SELECT isbn
     FROM
         (SELECT SUM(quantity) as totalsold, ba.isbn as isbn
          FROM BookAuthor ba
          JOIN Author a ON ba.authorid = a.authorid
          JOIN OrderItems oi ON ba.isbn = oi.isbn
          GROUP BY ba.isbn
          ORDER BY totalsold DESC)
     WHERE rownum = 1)
```

However in theory there could be a tie for the MAX value and I stuck on how to return the associated isbn tied to the MAX value(s).

In essence how to do this query without using WHERE rownum = 1.

I came up with this but seems over clunky but it works:

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM Books b
JOIN BookAuthor ba ON b.isbn = ba.isbn
JOIN Author a ON ba.authorid = a.authorid
WHERE b.isbn IN 
    (SELECT ISBN
    FROM
        (SELECT SUM(quantity) as totalsold, ba.isbn as isbn
         FROM BookAuthor ba
         JOIN Author a ON ba.authorid = a.authorid
         JOIN OrderItems oi ON ba.isbn = oi.isbn
         GROUP BY ba.isbn)
    WHERE totalsold = 
        (SELECT MAX(totalsold)
        FROM
            (SELECT SUM(quantity) as totalsold, ba.isbn as isbn
             FROM BookAuthor ba
             JOIN Author a ON ba.authorid = a.authorid
             JOIN OrderItems oi ON ba.isbn = oi.isbn
             GROUP BY ba.isbn)))
```

Comment: You don't really need to do all this joins in your subqueries. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Are you allowed to use analytic functions?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong.

1. You need firstly find a number, that represents max sold books. This
       query will return one number. Say $maxNumber
2. Then you need to find ALL books that where sold the same number as $maxNumber
3. Then you will find authors by joining with books from step 2

I'll give you subquery that return to you set of isbn(s) of book that were sold max copies.

```
SELECT 
    oi2.isbn
FROM
    OrderItems oi2
WHERE
    SUM(oi2.quantity) = (SELECT MAX(st.sumtotal) as total FROM (SELECT 
            SUM(oi.quantity) AS sumtotal
        FROM
            OrderItems oi
        GROUP BY oi.isbn) st) GROUP BY oi2.isbn
```

Now you can join it or use it as subquery for IN(subquery) function. You will need also to do GROUP BY author_id, because on author can have 2 books that were sold the same max copies.

Depending on the final requirement, you need to build different queries in case you want the author's name only or the authors' name with names of books.

Comment: Don't think there is a difference in the values on using 'IN' vs '=' I'm more concerned with using 'rownum = 1' since this will only return one value no matter what.